# Unable to use jquery scrollto plugin - getting error "targ is undefined..."

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollto

I am using jquery 1.3.2 in my project. I selected the 1.3.x option from the scrollto download page ->

http://plugins.jquery.com/node/635/release?api_version[]=1266 and tried with both the available options there -
ScrollTo 1.4.2 and ScrollTo 1.4.1.

but I am getting this error in both cases.

**Here is the code part -**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{

if($('tr#manager-'+agencyId).length)>0)
    $('tr#manager-'+agencyId).scrollTo();
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
```

But I am getting this error in firefox ->

```
targ is undefined
attr[key] = targ[pos];  (jquery.scrollto line 157)
```

And in IE 8 ->

```
Message: 'targ' is null or not an object
Line: 157
Char: 6
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:9001/js/jquery.scrollTo.js
```

The error appears only on calling `.scrollTo()`.

Anybody faced this issue. What else do I need to check? Any pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide a target that the plugin can scroll to.

Comment: ohhh you got it... I just guessed  `$('tr#manager-'+agencyId).scrollTo();` would scroll to $('tr#manager-'+agencyId). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('tr#manager-'+agencyId).length)>0)
```

there's an extra bracket after `length`.

Comment: hey that happened while putting the question. :) Sorry